# Improving the performance of a long query

Tags: oracle, performance

I have a query that i have let run for a few hours.  I am forced to kill the query because it is taking up 60% of the CPU.  Is there anything i can do to improve its performance?

```
select distinct(random_selection.randnum), 
    random_selection.dropper_id, 
    random_selection.ozip3 
from random_selection 
where random_selection.dropper_id is not null 
and random_selection.quarter = 121
and (random_selection.dropper_id, random_selection.randnum, random_selection.quarter) in 
    (select forecast_entry.dropper, forecast_entry.rand_num, production_weeks.yyq 
    from forecast_entry, production_weeks 
    where forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week 
    and production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC' 
    and production_weeks.yyq >= 121)

union 

select distinct(random_selection.randnum), 
    dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id, 
    random_selection.ozip3 
from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2, dropper 
where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 
and dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id 
and dropper.active = 1 
and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002 
and random_selection.quarter = 121
and random_selection.dropper_id is null 
and (random_selection.dropper_id, random_selection.randnum, random_selection.quarter) in 
    (select forecast_entry.dropper, forecast_entry.rand_num, production_weeks.yyq 
    from forecast_entry, production_weeks 
    where forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week 
    and production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC' 
    and production_weeks.yyq >= 121)
```

Query explained:

the main objective is to get all of the randnum, dropper_id, and ozip3 from random_selection table that are not in the forecast_entry table and are in yyq 121 and have a project code of EXFC.  yyq is retrieved from the production_weeks table by associating week and production_week. Some dropper_id are null so we need to pull that data from the dropper_city_brk_2 table by associating ozip3 and zip3.  We dont want dropper_id that are inactive so they must have active equal 1, this is by associating the dropper table.

Answer (score 4):

The performance bottleneck very likely arises from the use of the `IN` keyword. You should rewrite it with an `EXISTS`. See the [accepted answer of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069346/general-rules-for-simplifying-sql-statements) on Stackoverflow for how to do it. I'm pasting the relevant part here (credit goes to Quassnoi and you have to adapt it to your SQL dialect if needed):

---

One of the most common things to do is replacing this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col IN
        (
        SELECT  othercol
        FROM    othertable
        )
```

with this one:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable mo
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    othertable o
        WHERE   o.othercol = mo.col
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the sub-selects are the same, you could consolidate that portion via `WITH`:

```
WITH exss AS
    ( SELECT forecast_entry.dropper,
            forecast_entry.rand_num,
            production_weeks.yyq
       FROM forecast_entry
       JOIN production_weeks
         ON ( forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week )
      WHERE production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC'
            AND production_weeks.yyq >= 121
    )
SELECT  random_selection.randnum,
        random_selection.dropper_id,
        random_selection.ozip3
    FROM random_selection
    JOIN exss
        ON ( random_selection.dropper_id = exss.dropper
            AND random_selection.randnum = exss.rand_num
            AND random_selection.quarter = exss.yyq )
    WHERE random_selection.dropper_id IS NOT NULL
        AND random_selection.quarter = 121
UNION
SELECT  random_selection.randnum,
        dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id,
        random_selection.ozip3
    FROM random_selection
    JOIN dropper_city_brk_2
        ON ( random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 )
    JOIN dropper
        ON ( dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id )
    JOIN exss
        ON ( random_selection.dropper_id = exss.dropper
            AND random_selection.randnum = exss.rand_num
            AND random_selection.quarter = exss.yyq )
    WHERE random_selection.dropper_id IS NOT NULL
        AND random_selection.quarter = 121
        AND dropper.active = 1
        AND dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
```

You could maybe even take it further and include the random_selection table in the `WITH` block:

```
WITH exss AS
    ( SELECT a.randnum,
            a.dropper_id,
            a.ozip3
       FROM random_selection a
       JOIN
            ( SELECT forecast_entry.dropper,
                    forecast_entry.rand_num,
                    production_weeks.yyq
               FROM forecast_entry
               JOIN production_weeks
                 ON ( forecast_entry.week = production_weeks.production_week )
              WHERE production_weeks.project_cd = 'EXFC'
                    AND production_weeks.yyq >= 121 ) b
         ON ( a.dropper_id = b.dropper
                AND a.randnum = b.rand_num
                AND a.quarter = b.yyq )
      WHERE a.dropper_id IS NOT NULL
            AND a.quarter = 121
    )
SELECT exss.randnum,
    exss.dropper_id,
    exss.ozip3
FROM exss
UNION
SELECT exss.randnum,
    dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id,
    exss.ozip3
FROM exss
JOIN dropper_city_brk_2
 ON ( exss.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 )
JOIN dropper
 ON ( dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id )
WHERE dropper.active = 1
    AND dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002
```

Avoid using `DISTINCT` in the query if at all possible.

Since I don't use the `WITH` construct on a frequent basis the syntax may be a bit off but it should at least get you close.

**edit** How large are these tables? Have you looked at the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the query? Indices?